# How to fix singular fit in linear mixed model?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am running a linear mixed model to see if reaction times on a task differ across subject, experimental condition, or target. However, when I run the lme it warns me about singular fit.

I understand that singular fit may indicate an overfitted model, but I don't understand why my models are overfitted with the amount of data I have.

For more information, the experiment involves subjects to name a series of pictures and we record the reaction times (RT). Each participant sees all pictures (targets) and has all 4 conditions. There are 440 targets with 110 targets in each condition.

My first model did not have a singular fit issue:

```
model1 = lmer(log(RTs300ms)~Condition+(1|Targets)+(1|Subject),data=beh_acc2)


REML criterion at convergence: -6030.481
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 Targets  (Intercept) 0.07918 
 Subject  (Intercept) 0.13678 
 Residual             0.17972 
Number of obs: 10985, groups:  Targets, 110; Subject, 27
Fixed Effects:
  (Intercept)    ConditionTh  ConditionUnTa  ConditionUnTh  
      6.67960       -0.03549       -0.01475       -0.01700
```

But then starting with my second model I started getting the issue:

```
model2 = lmer(log(RTs300ms)~Condition+(1|Targets)+(1+Condition|Subject),data=beh_acc2)

REML criterion at convergence: -6037.6

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.3985 -0.6456 -0.1593  0.4551  5.3105 

Random effects:
Groups   Name          Variance  Std.Dev. Corr             
Targets  (Intercept)   6.270e-03 0.079184                  
 Subject  (Intercept)   1.947e-02 0.139546                  
          ConditionTh   2.482e-05 0.004982  0.58            
          ConditionUnTa 2.273e-04 0.015078 -0.50  0.41      
          ConditionUnTh 1.200e-04 0.010956 -0.64  0.26  0.99
 Residual               3.226e-02 0.179597                  
Number of obs: 10985, groups:  Targets, 110; Subject, 27

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    6.679624   0.028108 237.641
ConditionTh   -0.035441   0.004949  -7.162
ConditionUnTa -0.014807   0.005648  -2.621
ConditionUnTh -0.017071   0.005293  -3.225

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CndtnT CondtnUnT
ConditionTh  0.022                 
ConditinUnT -0.321  0.463          
ConditnUnTh -0.321  0.471  0.597   
convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

Ideally, I would want my final model to work, but it is the most complex of the three:

```
model3 = lmer(log(RTs300ms)~Condition+(1+Condition|Targets)+(1+Condition|Subject),data=beh_acc2)

REML criterion at convergence: -6068.3

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7.3684 -0.6393 -0.1575  0.4541  5.2834 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name          Variance  Std.Dev. Corr             
 Targets  (Intercept)   6.931e-03 0.083252                  
          ConditionTh   1.008e-03 0.031748 -0.19            
          ConditionUnTa 1.419e-03 0.037676 -0.35  0.58      
          ConditionUnTh 1.727e-03 0.041553 -0.29  0.72  0.98
 Subject  (Intercept)   1.951e-02 0.139662                  
          ConditionTh   2.575e-05 0.005074  0.57            
          ConditionUnTa 2.371e-04 0.015399 -0.50  0.43      
          ConditionUnTh 1.237e-04 0.011124 -0.63  0.28  0.99
 Residual               3.187e-02 0.178527                  
Number of obs: 10985, groups:  Targets, 110; Subject, 27

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    6.679466   0.028234 236.574
ConditionTh   -0.035074   0.005785  -6.063
ConditionUnTa -0.014748   0.006706  -2.199
ConditionUnTh -0.016823   0.006607  -2.546

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CndtnT CondtnUnT
ConditionTh -0.008                 
ConditinUnT -0.325  0.497          
ConditnUnTh -0.306  0.548  0.722   
convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

I am not sure how to resolve the singular fit issue I get on model2 and model3. I have read some recommendations to try Bayesian models, which I am unfamiliar with.

Any advice or further recommendations on this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you read `?lme4::isSIngular` and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378939/dealing-with-singular-fit-in-mixed-models and https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#singular-models-random-effect-variances-estimated-as-zero-or-correlations-estimated-as---1 yet ... ?

Comment: When you fit `(1+Condition|g)` (where `g` is a grouping variable), you're trying to estimate the parameters of a 4x4 covariance matrix = 4*(4+1)/2=10 parameters. When `g=Target` you have 110 observations, so that *might* work (as a rule of thumb, you need 10-20 times as many observations as parameters); when `g=Subject` you have 27 observations, so that's almost certain not to work.

Comment: @BenBolker I haven't read that particular post yet - thank you for your help, I'll take a look at those!

Answer (score 2):

In your first model, you don't include any random effects.  However, in the models that return your error you have now included a random effect of condition.  My guess is that there is actually no randomness in your effect of condition.

You can check with the `rePCA` function from `lme4` with the following code: `summary(rePCA(model2))`.  The result will provide a table that provides the proportion of variance explained in your random effect structure.  If you have any column that explains near 0 proportion of variance, this is likely the issue and is causing the singular fit error. Another way to confirm this, is to plot out the mean RT for each condition by participant to create what's called a "spaghetti plot". Add lines and group them by the participant so that you can see the changes in RTs for each condition by the participant.  If the lines are all parallel (or nearly parallel), then this would indicate that there is likely no randomness in your effect of condition.

Comment: Okay, thank you that's very helpful! I see there's an issue with one of the columns accounting for 0 proportion of variance that's probably it then.

Comment: @ElizabethAnderson If you find something helpful, please upvote it and accept the answer. This will help others navigate more quickly to the answer.